# Accessing values of dictionary 3 levels deep in Jinja2

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I have a dictionary defined in a somefile.jinja2 file:

```
{%
   set virtual_servers = {
    'pc_k8snode': {
          'server1': {
              'name': 'server001',
              'ip_address': '10.10.10.10',
          },
          'server2': {
              'name': 'server002',
              'ip_address': '20.20.20.20',
          },
          'server_state': 'ENABLED',
          'service_protocol': 'HTTP',
          'service_port': '80',
          'cs_ip_address': '30.30.30.30',
          'cs_port': '443',
    },
  },
%}
```

I have another jinja2 file called template.jinja2 that imports somefile.jinja2:

```
{%- import somefile.jinja2' as device -%}

{% for vs in device.virtual_servers %}
    {% for servers in vs %}
        {% for srv in vs[servers] %}
add server {{ srv }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It currently prints out:

```
add server server1
add server server2
add server server_state
add server service_protocol
add server service_port
add server cs_ip_address
add server cs_port
```

server1 and server2 are 3 levels deep. I would like to print out the following output:

```
add server server001 10.10.10.10
add server server002 20.20.20.20
```

Comment: `vs[servers][srv]["name"]`  and `vs[servers][srv]["ip_address"]` ?

Comment: But it may need to check if `vs[servers][srv]` is a dict to skip `name`,`ip_address` when you display `service_protocol`, `service_port`, etc.

Comment: @furas Thanks! how do I check if the keys exist in jinja2? Unlike in Python, it doesn't have "break" for forloops.... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vs[servers][srv]["name"]` and `vs[servers][srv]["ip_address"]`

You can also use these values with `if` to skip `name`, `ip_address` when you display other values.

```
{%- import 'somefile.jinja2' as device -%}

{%- for vs in device.virtual_servers %}
    {%- for servers in vs -%}
        {%- for srv in vs[servers] -%}
{%- if vs[servers][srv]["name"] %}        
add server {{ vs[servers][srv]["name"] }} {{ vs[servers][srv]["ip_address"] }}
{%- else %}
add server {{ srv }} {{ vs[servers][srv] }}
{%- endif %}
        {%- endfor %}
    {%- endfor %}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Result:

```
add server server001 10.10.10.10        
add server server002 20.20.20.20
add server server_state ENABLED
add server service_protocol HTTP
add server service_port 80
add server cs_ip_address 30.30.30.30
add server cs_port 443
```

---

**BTW:**

In `jinja` you can also use `.items()` and `.values()` or `.keys()`

```
{%- for server in vs.values() -%}
```

```
{%- for key, val in server.items() -%}
```

And in your template it could be

```
{%- import 'somefile.jinja2' as device -%}

{%- for vs in device.virtual_servers %}
    {%- for server in vs.values() -%}
        {%- for key, val in server.items() -%}
{%- if val["name"] %}        
add server {{ val["name"] }} {{ val["ip_address"] }}
{%- else %}
add server {{ key }} {{ val }}
{%- endif %}
        {%- endfor %}
    {%- endfor %}
{%- endfor -%}
```

---

If you need only servers then skip `else`

```
{%- import 'somefile.jinja2' as device -%}

{%- for vs in device.virtual_servers %}
    {%- for server in vs.values() -%}
        {%- for key, val in server.items() -%}
{%- if val["name"] %}        
add server {{ val["name"] }} {{ val["ip_address"] }}
{%- endif %}
        {%- endfor %}
    {%- endfor %}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Or you should keep `server1`,`server2` as subdictionary ie. `"servers": {"server1": ... , "server2": ...}`  and use only `device.virtual_servers["servers"]`

You could also keep other values in subdictionary i.e. `"options"{ {"server_state": ..., "service_protocol": ..., ...}` and then it could be simpler to display only options because you could use only `device.virtual_servers["options"]`

```
{%
   set virtual_servers = {
    'pc_k8snode': {
    
          'servers': {
              'server1': {
                  'name': 'server001',
                  'ip_address': '10.10.10.10',
              },
              'server2': {
                  'name': 'server002',
                  'ip_address': '20.20.20.20',
              },
          }, 
          
          'options': {
              'server_state': 'ENABLED',
              'service_protocol': 'HTTP',
              'service_port': '80',
              'cs_ip_address': '30.30.30.30',
              'cs_port': '443',
          }
    }
  }
%}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Code which I used to render templates

**main.py**

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, select_autoescape

env = Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader("main"),  # I run `main.py` so it should use `main`
    autoescape=select_autoescape()
)

template = env.get_template("main.jinja2")

print(template.render())
```

Comment: Hi furas, from your result, I just need the first two lines printed. How do I skip or break out of the loop after the second line? There is no 'break' in jinja2 like in Python...

Comment: remove `{% else %}` and `add server {{ srv }} {{ vs[servers][srv] }}`

Comment: eventually you should keep `server1`, `server2` as subdictionary `servers: {server1: ... , server2: ...}` and later use only `device.virtual_servers["servers"]`

Comment: Hi @furas. I just tried copying and pasting your code but the output was nothing when rendered. I think they issue may be somewhere in the second line... {%- for servers in vs -%} ... if you try and print 'vs' it's prints 'pc_k8snode'

Comment: well I don't have your code which generate template so I could create code which works different then your code. I add this code at the end of answer. OR maybe I made too many experiments and finally I put wrong version in answer ;)

Comment: last version should be the same as previous but without `else` - I put correct version (at least works with my code and with original `somefile.jinja2`).